# Woocommerece Products slider with item count

Tags: woocommerce

I searching in google about what i want but i can't found any plugin meet my needs

I need to display product in slider and when make slide item count change like in attachment **beside Pesta & Seafood (1-4 of 9)**

[image]

Comment: That depends on the slider you are using. Ill recommend using Slick , Owl Carousel , FlexSlider or any other that have built in events to handle counting.

Comment: could you giv me code to make this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example using Slick carousel
Here is preview of the result - https://prnt.sc/NNKZ-fPkCjDF
How to integrate it in your project - https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

This is the html structure

```
<div class="carousel-with-counter">
    <div class="counter">
        <span class="current"></span> of <span class="total"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel">
        <div class="item"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/270x200/000/fff" /></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/270x200/000/fff" /></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/270x200/000/fff" /></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/270x200/000/fff" /></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/270x200/000/fff" /></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/270x200/000/fff" /></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/270x200/000/fff" /></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/270x200/000/fff" /></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/270x200/000/fff" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the js code

```
(function ($) {  
    $(document).ready(function() {
        carousel_with_counter();
    });
    function carousel_with_counter() {
        var $carousel = $('.carousel-with-counter .carousel');

        $carousel.on('init reInit afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
            var totalSlides = slick.slideCount;
            var slidesToShow = slick.options.slidesToShow;
            var slideRangeStart = slick.slickCurrentSlide() + 1;
            var slideRangeEnd = Math.min(slideRangeStart + slidesToShow - 1, totalSlides);

            var slideRange = slideRangeStart + '-' + slideRangeEnd;

            $('.carousel-with-counter .counter .current').text(slideRange);
            $('.carousel-with-counter .counter .total').text(totalSlides);
        });

        $carousel.slick({
            slidesToShow: 4,
            slidesToScroll: 4,
            arrows: true,
            dots: false,
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Here is how to use it as shortcode - shortcode should look like **`[carousel_with_counter ids="1,2,3,4"]`**

```
add_shortcode('carousel_with_counter','products_for_carousel');
function products_for_carousel($atts) {
    
    $product_ids = explode(",", $atts['ids']);

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post__in' => $product_ids
    );
    
    ob_start();
    $q = new WP_Query($args);

    if($q->have_posts()):
    echo '<div class="carousel-with-counter"><div class="counter"><span class="current"></span> of <span class="total"></span></div>';
        echo '<div class="carousel">';
            while($q->have_posts()): $q->the_post();
                echo '<div class="item">';
                    wc_get_template_part('content','product');
                echo '</div>';
            endwhile;
        echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    endif;
    wp_reset_query();
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $content;
}
```

Alternative solution with taxonomy term_id
Here is how to use it as shortcode - shortcode should look like **`[carousel_with_counter id="1"]`**

```
add_shortcode('carousel_with_counter','products_for_carousel');
function products_for_carousel($atts) {
    
    $category_id = $atts['id']);

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1, //Since we query by taxonomy we may have alot of products feel free to restrict
        'tax_query' => array(
          array(
           'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
           'field' => 'term_id',
           'terms' => $category_id 
          )
        )
    );
    
    ob_start();
    $q = new WP_Query($args);

    if($q->have_posts()):
    echo '<div class="carousel-with-counter"><div class="counter"><span class="current"></span> of <span class="total"></span></div>';
        echo '<div class="carousel">';
            while($q->have_posts()): $q->the_post();
                echo '<div class="item">';
                    wc_get_template_part('content','product');
                echo '</div>';
            endwhile;
        echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    endif;
    wp_reset_query();
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Martin Mirchev
But i need for woocommerce product

Comment: I updated my answer with shortcode since i dont know where and how you want ot use it and it was not part of the question. Also based on this shortcode you can modify it as you wish. The concept will be the same.

Comment: Thanks Martin Mirchev But ,buti want get product by category
Help Me Plz

Comment: I have added example